# Are Data Explorer Queries included in the Data Dump?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump, data-analysis

Since the Data Dump includes all the Stack Exchange sites, is Data Explorer included? If not, is there a way to backup queries besides copy/paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data dump is a set of XML files, not a database snapshot. Including SQL queries with it wouldn't make much sense.

Our installation of the data explorer saves all queries, so you can easily find the ones you wrote by going to your profile and the ones someone else wrote by marking them as favorite.

Comment: Thanks Anna. Is there a backup of Data Explorer in case the hardware fails?

Comment: @PaulSweatte I believe so, but I'm not 100% sure.